# String to array or hashtable

Tags: regex, powershell, webrequest

We're trying to do error handling on the `Invoke-WebReqeust` Cmdlet. What is commonly used is something like this:

```
Try {
    # Invoke-WebRequest ....
}
catch {
    $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
    $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
    $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
    $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();
    Write-Host $responseBody
}
```

When an error is detected the following `String` will be returned:

> { "Error": "AdmConDataError: None (IBDataConflictError: IB.Data.Conflict:MAC address 03:03:33:33:33:36 is used in two fixed addresses 10.20.32.1 and 10.20.32.1, which are in the
>   same network 10.20.32.0/24.)",
>     "code": "Client.Ibap.Data.Conflict",
>     "text": "MAC address 03:03:33:33:33:36 is used in two fixed addresses 10.20.32.1 and 10.20.32.1, which are in the same network 10.20.32.0/24."
>   }

We're now trying to parse the `String` to an `Array` or a `hashtable` for ease of use. The desired result would be:

```
@{
    Error = 'AdmConDataError: None (IBDataConflictError: IB.Data.Conflict:MAC address 03:03:33:33:33:36 is used in two fixed addresses 10.20.32.1 and 10.20.32.1, which are in the same network 10.20.32.0/24.)'
    Code  = 'Client.Ibap.Data.Conflict'
    text  = 'MAC address 03:03:33:33:33:36 is used in two fixed addresses 10.20.32.1 and 10.20.32.1, which are in the same network 10.20.32.0 / 24.'
}
```

With the help of other posts we were thinking about falling back on `regexes`. But we can't seem to get it right. We tried with `-match '(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")'` to match everything between double quoted brackets, but that's clearly not sufficient. Any ideas on a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error string in the example is valid JSON.

You can simply do `$responseBody | ConvertFrom-Json` to obtain an object with (among the default method members) three NoteProperties:

- code
- Error
- text

Answer (score 1):

The returned string looks like simple JSON, so you could convert it like this:

```
$resultString = '{ "Error": "AdmConDataError: None (IBDataConflictError: IB.Data.Conflict:MAC address 03:03:33:33:33:36 is used in two fixed addresses 10.20.32.1 and 10.20.32.1, which are in the same network 10.20.32.0/24.)", "code": "Client.Ibap.Data.Conflict", "text": "MAC address 03:03:33:33:33:36 is used in two fixed addresses 10.20.32.1 and 10.20.32.1, which are in the same network 10.20.32.0/24." }'

$result = $resultString | ConvertFrom-Json
```

You can, of course, combine these steps, it's just a bit clearer like this.  In any case, `$result` will contain a 'PsCustomObject' with properties 'Error', 'Code' and 'Text', which you can then access with the usual syntax:

```
$result.Code
Client.Ibap.Data.Conflict
```